# Killed:9 when running app with entitlements

Tags: swift, macos, macos-mojave

I am developing an app in swift, on macOS Mojave with Xcode 10, which has been running fine during development.

As I am preparing for deployment I discovered that running the app on another machine results in an immediate crash. Running from the terminal produces a single line message “Killed:9”. If I start it from lldb, the app runs fine. If I switch off it’s entitlements in Xcode (sandbox and keychain sharing) then it runs fine.

I created another simple test app with the same entitlements and that runs fine from the command line.

I have been through my project settings and scoured the internet, but can’t work out what I am missing.

Any ideas folks ?

Comment: I should add I have cleared Xcode’s caches and done clean builds, to no avail. I can only run the app outside of lldb if I switch off sandbox and shared keychain.

Answer (score 2):

After exploring all sorts of different avenues, it turns out the problem was to do with code signing.

I had an embedded dynamic library which expected to be in `/usr/local/lib`

This was fixed this by a run script build phase to change the name of the library to `@rpath/lib...` in each of the frameworks that used it with `install_name_tool`.

This worked fine while debugging, but for release Xcode was signing the libraries during the copy phase, and the `install_name_tool` script was corrupting the libraries signature.

I tried various ways to resign the library and/or app after this run script phase, but nothing worked. Finally I had to fix the library itself before building the rest of the app, and do away with the `install_name_tool` script which was breaking the signature. The app was finally able to run again from a release build.